# Nonfiction: Need signed releases and/or pay subjects I am interviewing?

Tags: legal, non-fiction

I am interested in writing a nonfiction book on social media. The book will be primarily practical advice based on my experience. However, I'm planning to personally interview some industry professionals to add their advice to the circle. I may even do Q&As with a few select people.

In journalism, it's no problem to use quotes from people. However, since this is a book, what are the rules or general practices concerning the content of an interview? Do I need to get them to sign a consent form? Do I need to pay the interview subjects?

Any advice is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. You might want to browse other questions under the "legal" tag to see if there are useful answers already posted (although caveat lector, I don't believe we have any lawyers on the board).

Comment: I didn't find any duplicates of this, but there are some related questions: [Legal and Social effect of story involving real life people](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/10644/26), [Do I need permission from people I am writing about if I am writing about a true story that was reported in the media?](http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/9308/26).

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of paying an interviewee for an article or book. I have never done it. There are books available on the art of the interview, which you should consult. You can record the interview, with permission (included in the recording) which is a protection for both writer and interviewee, and is a release of sorts; you can offer to provide pertinent sections of your final article or book *in context*. Any publisher is going to make certain there are no litigious issues prior to publication; but many contracts allow the publisher to hang you out to dry if you are involved in legal issues after publication, so consult an attorney before the interview.